# Java, ByteBuffer convert to byte[], what is different between array() and get()?

Tags: java

ByteBuffer buffer = ....;

method 1:

```
byte [] array = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
buffer.get(array);
```

method2:

```
byte [] array = = buffer.array();
```

Comment: Well, aside from the typo in the second snippet one obvious difference would be that in the first snippet _you_ have control over which array is used (you could even reuse one) while the second snippet would return the array used by the byte buffer _internally_. That also means that in the first snippet you get a copy of the array while in the second snipped you would be able to modify the byte buffer by modifying the array - as documented in the JavaDocs on those 2 methods.

Comment: In addition to what Thomas said: If the `ByteBuffer` is _direct_, or is otherwise not backed by an accessible array, then the `#array()` method will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Call `get()` and you will copy the data into a new `byte[]`.
Calling `array()` for `HeapByteBuffer` will likely return the `byte[]` array of ByteBuffer underlying data.
For `DirectByteBuffer`, because it uses direct memory, calling `array()` will throw an exception.